Stop blowing your load in the Golden Arches
While doing some research I came across the following phrase:

“Young men do not need to proactively freeze their sperm,” says David Ryley, a reproductive endocrinologist at Boston IVF. “If men want to enhance their fertility, they should do what they know they should be doing.” That being: limit yourself to two drinks a day, don’t smoke and stop blowing your load in the Golden Arches.

I'm clear on the blowing your load part, but what do McDonald's Golden Arches have to do with this? The best I can come up with is it's some obscure euphemism for breasts, although why exactly a pearl necklace would enhance fertility for the sperm still in the body is beyond me. Is this just a throwaway joke (i.e. make sure you're ejaculating in the right place), or have I missed some Americanism here?

It's definitely unclear, but if we expect this joke to make any sense medically, I think we can surmise the speaker's intended meaning.
Frequent masturbation does not appear to affect male fertility (Mayo Clinic).
What does affect fertility is diet:

Trans fat and "unhealthy diets" (those "rich in red and processed meats, potatoes, sweets, and sweetened beverages") were found to have negative effects [on fertility].

Harvard Health Blog
So the colorful (and confusing) phrase was most likely to have meant: don't eat at McDonald's (and by extension any fast food, or unhealthy food in general).  This would fit well into the rest of the advice being given: limit alcohol, don't smoke, don't eat junk food.
Golden Arches simply means McDonald's, as it typically does.  And blow your load seems then not to have the sexual connotation, but rather this meaning:


To lose or spend all of one's money. 
My Las Vegas trip was short-lived—I blew my load at the poker table in the first two hours!
Here's $20 for the weekend, don't blow your whole load tonight.
Why is it that so many lottery winners blow their load and end up penniless?


Farlex Dictionary of Idioms
or


To expend one's resources or one's opportunity, especially prematurely; to blow one's chance.

He blew his load in the first round and went home early.

Wiktionary
This usage seems like kind of a stretch, but I guess the speaker thought the double entendre was worth it.

While I am not sure, I think "Men's Health" could be characterised as a "lads mag", and so the double entendre could have justified the whole paragraph.

Yes, this is probably what was on the writer's mind, but the metaphor is ill suited for the author's own purposes, because it focuses on what one spends, money, while what is relevant to the point of the sentence is presumably what one ingests, food. The effects of fast food on fertility would be the same if it were free. We have here yet another unfortunate case of the contributors to this site spending vastly more time and energy on analysing somebody's bad, half-baked writing than that person spent on the writing itself.

@jsw29, that’s fair.  I was originally writing this as a comment, but the explanation of the idiom’s other uses seemed to justify it being an answer instead.

@jsw29 I must admit that, when I read this question, I had no idea what it meant either. I don't think the question is unreasonable.

@alphabet, I had no idea what was intended either, but that's because the passage is badly written, and should just be dismissed as such, not because it embodies some subtle quirk of the language that is worthy of being patiently explicated here. It worries me that by trying at great lenght to clear up isolated cases of careless writing, which would otherwise be justly forgotten, we may be immortalising them.
